# How does instagram handle top likes when there are millions of likes for a particular post?

Tags: bigtable

Under each Instagram post is a text like this :

> friendA, friendB and 32,312 others liked this post

Saving count of likes in a column can be an easy way to get related data.

But the fact that Instagram shows specific results based on each persons friends, makes me wonder how do they do that ? retrieving and processing such a many to many relationship of user's follows with potentially millions of likes for a post sounds like a huge resource heavy action that even Facebook might have trouble handling.

And it certainly happens server side for two reasons:

A) When there are millions of likes, it would've taken minutes before all like data was downloaded by user.

B) You can see that Instagram returns top likes from backend. for example for this post [Justin Bieber's page](https://www.instagram.com/p/Ce6IR1wOKPE/) there is a request to this endpoint [Instagram Api endpoint](https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/media/2862636923467899844/info/) which returns an object including :

```
like_count  3213371
has_liked   false
top_likers  [ "friendA" ]
```

So my question is what tricks do they use to have this functionality at scales ?

Answer (score 1):

Only someone who works for Instagram can tell you exactly what they're doing, but to solve the kind of problem you described, just proper indexing and query design should be sufficient to be performant.

32,312 is a *small* number of records in the database world, especially relative to a table that may store billions of records overall. When indexed properly, this would likely result in an index seek operation, which would find those 32,312 records very quickly (because indexes store the data ordered by the fields defined in them). They have a good [selectivity](https://orangematter.solarwinds.com/2018/07/18/what-is-database-index-selectivity/) in such a large table.

Then joining these 32,312 records to a particular user's friends (which should also be indexed accordingly) is going to be very quick since the average person doesn't have a billion friends on Instagram. Rather they'll also have a small number of friends under 100,000.

Finally, since they're `LIMIT`ing the results to show only a couple of the friends who liked the post, the database system typically can *short-circuit* the join as soon as it finds the number of matching friends the query is requesting. In this case only 2 friends need to match. Depending on the database system they're using, it's either the `LIMIT` or `TOP` keyword that's used in the query to instruct this.

The above can all be accomplished in under a second on a modern laptop's hardware, so imagine what kind of hardware Instagram uses to back their database. Additionally, they may use some process of caching to bring the aforementioned sub-second process down to only a few milliseconds. But either way, sub-second is rather sufficiently performant.

Comment: Well 32,312 was an arbitrary number, the post i mentioned has over 3 million likes and is not even to be unique there many others in millions range. While I'm quite sure that they do limit queries, but it wont be a magical solution as there are many posts with no mutual likes and that means the whole table should be scanned.

Comment: is not even close to be considered a unique case *

Comment: @PooyaEstakhri Even 3 million is *small* compared to billions of rows in the table and makes for good selectivity. So no, the whole table wouldn't need to be scanned. The `LIMIT` *short-circuits* the search to only have to actually find **any** 2 friend records that match, making it very fast. It's really that simple (for 90% of it). I've *been there done that* for tables in the 10s of billions of rows, like I previously mentioned on hardware comparable to a modern laptop lol.